# javascript interval won't stop (clearInterval issue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I set up an interval which executes some API calls each X seconds, I will do this for the length of an array and increment a counter, esentially acting as a timed for loop, problem is the timer won't stop after reaching the length of my array, can you guys see where's the issue?

```
async startScrapingGridInterval()
    {
        const self = this;
        let currentPolygon = null;

        self.currentCell = 0;
        currentPolygon = self.polygonsArray[self.currentCell];
        currentPolygon.setOptions({fillColor: 'green', fillOpacity:0.4});

        self.handler = setInterval(function()
        {
            self.scrapeApi == 'Foursquare'  ? self.scrapeCellWithFoursquare(self.zoneBoundaries[self.currentCell]) : self.scrapeCellWithPlaces(self.zoneBoundaries[self.currentCell]);
            
            self.currentCell = self.currentCell+1;
            
            currentPolygon = self.polygonsArray[self.currentCell];
            currentPolygon.setOptions({fillColor: 'green', fillOpacity:0.4});
                
            //Why wont clearInterval work?
            if (self.currentCell >= self.zoneBoundaries.length)
            {
                clearInterval(self.handler);
                console.info('Finished scraping the whole grid in '+self.address);
                
            }

        }, self.scrapeCellDelay);

    },
```

Comment: does `startScrapingGridInterval` get called more than once?

Answer (score 1):

1. It's a good practice to clear the existing interval before setting a new one.

```
clearInterval(self.handler);

self.handler = setInterval(function() ...
```

2. Check if the log "Finished scaping ...." is printed.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure  "Finished scraping the whole grid .."  is printed

```
let count=0;
var handle=setInterval(function(){
    count++;
    if(count >10){
            clearInterval(handle);
            console.log("Finish");
    }
    console.log(count);
},500)
```